# How to insert column from dataframe into SQL Server with pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert data from a CSV (or DataFrame) into MS SQL Server.
The table has already been created, and I created the columns in SQL using pyodbc.

I'm trying to populate the first column in a table with one column from the DataFrame but I get this error:

> Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I've tried adding a different column to see if it was an issue with that specific column and I get the same error. (There are no null values in the column.)

```py
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};" 
                      "Server=natsqldevap2ncr\ins2;"
                      "Database=ECDWDEV;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

for i in df.iloc[:,0]:
    insert_query1 =  """INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
                   VALUES 
                   (?)"""

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(insert_query1)
    conn.commit()
```

Expecting all the values in the column (df.iloc[:,0]) to be inserted into the column "COLUMN_NAME" in the SQL table "TABLE_NAME".

Instead get:

> Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Pushing data from PYODBC to SQL is a very bad idea. I would just find another solution conpletely. Such as saving your CSV and manually uploading, or some efficient bulk-upload methods from Python.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `i` you're just running your `insert_query1` as many times as there are rows in `df`.  Is that what you intent to do?

Comment: @FatihAkici Why is it a bad idea? What bulk-upload method would be better?

Comment: @it's-yer-boy-chet well ideally I would just load the entire column in one go, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error message because you are trying to use a parameterized query but you are not passing the parameter *values* to the `execute` method.

Besides, you don't need to insert row-by-row by calling `execute` in an explicit `for` loop. You can use `executemany` instead:

```python
# test data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(1, 'Josh', 10000), (2, 'Michael', 5000), (3, 'Sara', 8000)],
    columns=['id', 'name', 'salary'])
#
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.fast_executemany = True
sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id) VALUES (?)"
# extract column and convert to list of single-value tuples
data = [(x,) for x in df['id']]
crsr.executemany(sql, data)
cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: I get an error "IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column". FYI there are no NULLS in the data. Is 'id' the name of the column in SQL? And in the dataframe?

Comment: "Is 'id' the name of the column in SQL? And in the dataframe?" - In the sample code above, yes, and normally we try to have the column names be the same at both ends, but that is not strictly necessary. As for nulls, there must be something in the column that maps to SQL `NULL`, perhaps `NaN`. A [mcve] would be very helpful.